# In Android 9 file size after unzip is 1024 bytes larger than the original file size

Tags: java, android

I ran into a strange problem. After unzip operation on Samsung S9/S9 +, it turned out that the size of the unpacked file is 1K larger than the size of the original file. For packaging and unpacking java.util.zip is used. Can anyone know about the problem? With what it can be connected?

Comment: Isn't that normal? I mean, it was zipped, you just unzipped it

Comment: @LppEddI think he means it's bigger than before he zipped it on another device. I think this is due to the way that the android filesystem works but I'm not certain so don't quote me on that.